# Active Directory - Roles of a user

Tags: c#, active-directory

I understand how to use `User.Identity` and `User.IsInRole`

Is there a way to see all of the roles a user is in?

We have a lot of groups and some people are in a lot of groups, but I don't want to write a User.IsInRole 20+ times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In an Active Directory context, the *Roles* you refer to are really the security (or authorization) groups a user is a member of.

So if you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // find a user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

   if(user != null)
   {
       // get the authorization groups - those are the "roles" 
       var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

       foreach(Principal principal in groups)
       {
           // do something with the group (or role) in question
       }
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!