# How do I get all Roles for current User?

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory, roles

I'm working on a Business Logic for a WPF-Application. Before the Application starts i have to prove if the CurrentUser is in the ActiveDirectory of a special Domain and if he is in there, i have to find out in which roles the current User is. Current user and his existence in AD is working fine but i have problems to find out the roles.

I've tried it with:

```
using System.Web.Security;

Roles.GetRolesForUser(currentuser);
```

but the Problem is, that i have to enable Role-Management so i wrote above the Code:

```
Roles.Enabled = true;
```

but there is still a problem with it --> `System.InvalidOperationException;`

Here's the whole Code (testversion):

```
string currentuser = Environment.UserName;
string currentmachine = Environment.MachineName;

if (DirectoryEntry.Exists(string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1}", currentmachine,  currentuser)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("it's working\n");


    Roles.Enabled = true;
    Console.WriteLine(Roles.GetRolesForUser(currentuser));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("it's not working");
}
```

Is it a problem with the using directive? Or are there other possibilities to check in which roles the user is?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help you: [Active Directory - Roles of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490227/active-directory-roles-of-a-user?lq=1)

In this post the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement-Namespace is used. 
I think this is the better way for a WPF-Application and Roles.GetRolesForUser seems to be used in ASP-Web-Applications.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: i'm using this directives: `using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.DirectoryServices;`

Comment: thank you - had to try a few things with the domain but now it#s working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you're also using memberships

```
var user = Membership.GetUser("WhateverUsername");
string [] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName);
```

If not then just specify the username:

```
string [] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser("WhateverUsename");
```

This will get the roles for the username you provided. Hope it helps.

Comment: there's still a problem with `System.InvalidOperationException;`

Comment: the Exception says: `This method can only be called during the initialization phase before the apllication starts.`

Comment: Try adding these in the appSettings area of your config file         <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>