# Get list of Roles, domain wise with Active Directory

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, roles

I was trying to list a list of roles from Active Directory in C#, but the only answers I've found so far are list of roles bound to a specific user, not a list of all roles domain wise.

This is the snippet I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490227/active-directory-roles-of-a-user)

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // find a user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

   if(user != null)
   {
       // get the authorization groups - those are the "roles" 
       var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

       foreach(Principal principal in groups)
       {
           // do something with the group (or role) in question
       }
   }
}
```

As you can see, the only way to get a list of roles is through the use of a `UserPrincipal` object which is bound to a user. I'd like to list all possible roles that can be assigned to a user from a specific domain.

By the way, I don't know so well the User/Group/Role Hierarchy in Active Directory, so I could be wrong when thinking about how that structure works, let's say, maybe a Role is just a special kind of group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
   GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer....
   }
}
```

This search starts at the top-level of the currently connected domain, and enumerate all groups in that domain. Now those can be both security group, as well as distribution list groups - if you want to get **security groups** (which really correspond to "roles"), you can adapt your searcher like this:

```
 GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
 qbeGroup.IsSecurityGroup = true;
```

See the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it and it lists about the same groups I was getting through another snippet. By the way, is it normal that if I set qbeGroup.IsSecurityGroup = false it returns an empty list? I don't know if it's normal to not have any "normal groups" and all of them are security groups.

Comment: @IvanMolinaHuerta: if you set `IsSecurityGroup=false`, then you get back **only** the (Exchange) distribution groups in your AD. If you don't have Exchange configured on that server, you might not have any of those - that's totally possible